# jQuery settimeout() not working while iterating over an array

Tags: jquery, arrays, settimeout

I have an array named jarray, i want to display the contents of the array, sequentially iterating from 3rd element to the 6th last element, the time for which i want to display ith cell of the array is 1sec, i tried the following code, but only the first element of the array gets displayed, please see my code below:

```
$(function() {
  var refreshId = setInterval(function(){
    for(var i=3;i<=jarray.length-5;i++){
      var r = (-0.5)+(Math.random()*(1000.99));
      $("p").text(jarray[i]);
    }
  }, 1000);
});
```

​html :

```
<p> Content not loaded yet </p>
```

Comment: Could you add the contents of jarray as well? Or you could add a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) link. It's length may be too short seeing that you start at 3 and end at 5 less than available.

Comment: no please  DO NOT worry about the array length and the contents, that is not a problem, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your entire for loop is in the function that executes every second. So the whole loop executes every second and you always end up seeing the last element it inserts.

Change all your code above to:

```
$(function(){
    var i = 3;
    (function insertArray(){
        $("p").text(jarray[i++]);
        if(i < jarray.length-5)
            setTimeout(insertArray, 1000);
    })();
});
```

Comment: edited the question, hope its clear now, let me go through your code and run it, i'll let you know.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var arrayCount = 0;
var intervalId = null;
$(function() {

  intervalId = setInterval(function(){
      if(arrayCount == jarray.length){
         clearInterval(intervalId);
         return;
      }
      $("p").text(jarray[arrayCount++]);

  }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, could you please tell me what was wrong with my code.

Comment: @Rahul - In your code you were the logic was completely wrong to get the index of the array to be displayed in each interval and also there is no code to clear the interval so it will never stop.

Answer (score -2):

Try with a closure... Of course ensure that jarray has been properly defined previously.

```
$(function() {
   var refreshId = setInterval(function(){
      for(var i=3;i<=jarray.length-5;i++){
         (function() {
            var r = (-0.5)+(Math.random()*(1000.99));
            jarrayi = jarray[i];
            $("p").text(jarrayi);
         }());
     }
  }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: What's this got to do with closure? How does it help?